# Cannot save macros when Umbraco 7 in virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, umbraco, web-deployment, umbraco7

I need to your help as I am new to Umbraco and deployment on IIS. I am deploying my Umbraco application under existing website like this:
[image]

But I am getting following error when save partial view macro in back office:
[image]

I don't want to create a new website instead add Umbraco as a new application under existing website.Please guide me!

Comment: What is your purpose in making the umbraco site a virtual application under the default site?

Comment: I want to switch my few existing website pages to umbraco but also want to keep running my existing website so run two websites in parallel - and the prerequisite is that the base URL doesn't change, which is in this format: www.existingwebsite.com/umbracosite